# Set Default Domain via Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to Powershell and had a question about `-DomainName` while using the `Add-Computer` command. Is there a way to set the default domain as part of that command so domain is set automatically at logon prompt:

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "Example".....
```

Or is the only way to add to registry on a second step:

```
Set-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon" -Name "DefaultDomain" -Value Example
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify that as part of `Add-Computer`. You can either set it in the registry as you show, or set it [through Group Policy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2908796/using-gpos-to-change-default-logon-domain-name-in-the-logon-screen) on the domain or OU that the computer is joined to.